# ngrx `forFeature` with multiple related entities

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

We are trying adopt a `forFeature` pattern for our app. However the multiple features are related.

We have an application where multiple entity relationships are shown simultaneously.

For example consider we have the following entities

- product
- supplier
- country
- currency
- harbour

Where as model

```
ìnterface Product {
  countryId: string;
  currencyId: string;
  supplierId: string;
}

interface Supplier {
  name: string;
  harbourId: string;
  countryId: string;
}
```

Then in the `product-detail` page we display the `currency` & `country` of a product and also the name and `country` of the `supplier`.

Consider we also have a `supplier-details page` where we display the above supplier infos as well as its last 10 products.

The way all this is currently handled is with a store structure as such:

```
 - entities
 ---- product
 ---- supplier
 ---- currency
 ---- country
 ---- harbour
 - ui
 ---- other stuff ui related
```

This is done with a single store at the root.

However the app folder structure is divided as such:

```
 - features
 --- product
 ------ product.actions / product.reducer / product.effects / product.selector
 --- supplier
 ------ supplier.actions / supplier.reducer / supplier.effects / supplier.selector
 --- store 
 ------ reducers ( here we are importing all reducers to combine those)
 ------ harbour.actions / harbour.reducer / harbour.effects / harbour.selector
 ------ country.actions / country.reducer / country.effects / country.selector
 ------ currency.actions / currency.reducer / currency.effects / currency.selector
```

As you can see the folder structure is a bit disorganized, as I'm not yet sure where to put `harbour`,  `country` & `currency` as some of them are kind of general entities.

However I'm looking at the `forFeature` bit of `ngrx` and I'm wondering how all this would fit together if we happen to use that and if features even can be used together.

- would each of those entity be a `forFeature` ?
- or should all this stuff be placed in one place and have an `entity` feature so my store would look the same as what it is now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forFeature` is meant to be used for reducers that need to be registered in a lazy manner a la `forChild` compared to `forRoot`.

I think a rule of thumb for this would be:

If the reducer is needed only for a particular lazy-loaded module, then it should be a `forFeature` for that module so it will only be registered once that module is loaded.

Once the reducer needs to be shared across modules (lazy loaded or not), then it needs to be at a higher level of abstraction in your app and should go to the `forRoot` version (globally accessible "at startup")

In summation:

- Your entity structure seems fine to me.
- I would put harbour/country/currency similar to how you did the others for file structure.
- Only use the slice of state in `forFeature` if it's only needed for that feature module, and that module is `lazy loaded`.